# How do I filter in linq query when field needs parsing first?

Tags: linq, parsing, linq-to-sql

I have a data table containing multiple columns and one column that stores somewhat complex text patterns - I need to parse the field to determine if a particular sub strings exist in specific positions within the larger string pattern and then if the record should be filtered out as a result.

I can't see a way to perform the parse other than by writing a C# parsing function with String.Split method calls, foreach, etc. But if I try to parse like this:

```
var myFilteredTable = _db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Column1 == 'Filter1' 
                                        && ParseIsMyItemInColumn2(t) );
```

I get "has no supported translation to SQL" errors.

The other option I thought of was to build the initial result without the Parse:

```
var myFilteredTable = _db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Column1 == 'Filter1' );
```

and iterate through the IQueryable resultset, testing each row with the parse function, to filter out the unwanted rows, but IQueryable does not have Remove function to strip out unwanted rows nor Add function to allow me to build  up a new resultset.

So how can I filter in linq when I also need to write a Parse function?

Comment: What is the code in the `ParseIsMyItemInColumn2()` method?  The operations you do there might not even be translatable to SQL.  If it is translatable, you can use a compiled query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the "initial filter in the database then do the rest locally" is easy:

```
var filtered = _db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Column1 == "Filter1")
                          .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest locally
                          .Where(t => ParseIsMyItemInColumn2(t));
```

[`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx) is a simple pass through method, but because the result is typed as `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQueryable<T>`, the subsequent LINQ operations use the LINQ to Objects methods in `Enumerable` rather than the ones in `Queryable`.

Obviously if a *lot* of items match the first filter but fail the second, that won't be terribly efficient...

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, if the "parse function" is not something that can be translated to SQL, you will need to pull the results and use LINQ to Objects:

```
var myFilteredTable = _db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Column1 == 'Filter1')
                         .AsEnumerable().Where(ParseIsMyItemInColumn2);
```

Note that this will stream all of the results into memory, and then perform your parse.